# asp.net GridView Row's id does not change controls clientid when in Predictable ClientIDMode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview being rendered in the format of:

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th></th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Our subclass of the gridview/row etc adds an id to each row

```cs
row.ID = "item" + row.DataItemIndex.ToString();
row.ClientIDMode = Predictable;
```

But when it gets rendered to the page the `ClientID` of the controls in the row don't have this id in them.

```html
<TABLE>
    <TBODY>
        <TR id="MainContent_mygridview">
            <TD>
                <SPAN id="MainContent_mygridview_label1_0">This is on page one</SPAN>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR id="MainContent_mygridview">
            <TD>
                <SPAN id="MainContent_mygridview_label1_1">This is on page one</SPAN>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
    <TBODY>
        <TR id="MainContent_mygridview">
            <TD>
                <SPAN id="MainContent_mygridview_label1_0">This is on page two</SPAN>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR id="MainContent_mygridview">
            <TD>
                <SPAN id="MainContent_mygridview_label1_1">This is on page two</SPAN>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

This becomes a problem because I have some ajax on the page that gets the next "page" worth of rows when requested and adds them to the gridview (as an extra `tbody`). This causes a clash of ID's in the DOM.

Comment: You say you have a gridview being rendered but you show static html in your example. Are you using the ASP.net GridView control or something else? Please show the actual code you are using.

Comment: @Shelly I should have said "being rendered like:" or "rendered in the following format:" .. I've edited it now to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So After digging around I found that the Predictable id uses the `DisplayIndex` Property of the `GridViewRow`.

```
int System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer.DisplayIndex
{
    get
    {
        return this.DataItemIndex;
    }
}
```

Also my subclass:

```
public class GridViewRow : 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow, System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer
```

I'm not sure why the subclass needed that as the system gridviewrow already implements that interface so maybe someone else could add to this.
Also I'm not sure if this is going to break anything else.

but now the elements get an id that ends in their DataItemIndex which makes them unique across the dataset instead of just the "page".